# How to plot this graph by using latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

[image: i want to plot this graph by tikz, can you]

I want to plot this graph using tikz, can you help me please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What have you tried so far?

Comment: It would be interesting, if not necessary, to know the functions that are graphed here.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 3):

I am not good at tikz (at all) but for start point I would recommend  You use this one example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 
\draw[ultra thick, black] (-0.3,3.7) .. controls (2.3,0.1) and (3.1,3.9) .. (5.1,4) .. controls (6.5,4.1) and (6.5,3) .. (8.2,2)node[black, above=15pt,pos=.9]{$f(x)$};

\draw[ultra thick, black] (-0.3,2.7) .. controls (2.3,-0.9) and (3.1,2.9) .. (5.1,3) .. controls (6.5,3.1) and (6.5,2) .. (8.2,1)node[black, below=15pt,pos=.7]{$f(x)$};

\filldraw[black] (0.6,2.7) circle (2pt) node[anchor=south] {$a_i^R$};

\draw[thick, red, dashed] (1.6,0)--(1.6,5);
\draw[thick, red, dashed] (5.2,0)--(5.2,5);
\draw [thick, ->] (-.5,2.7)--(8.3,2.7) node[below]{$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]